# quartz device behaving strangely after mac update - R mac

Tags: r, macos, graphics, core-graphics

I recently got a new macbook pro (2020 13-inch, running Big Sur v 11.1) and am using Rstudio (V 1.3.1093 with R version 4.0.3).

On my old computer, I often used the `quartz()` function to view my plots in the external graphics viewer. On my old mac, this would allow me to dynamically resize, keep fonts consistent, save directly from the resized version, etc. Now, on my new computer, it is behaving... strangely.

For example, when I run `quartz()` and a window opens, then I run a `ggplot`, the quartz window remains completely blank until I resize it just a tiny bit, then my plot appears. Even after the plot appears, sometimes the corners are cut off until I resize again, which then (I guess) refreshes the plot so it properly fills the space. The behavior with `ggsave` seems off, too, like the plots aren't saving exactly how they are appearing, which is the whole point of using the device.

Is anyone else having similar problems? I don't understand in great detail how graphics devices work, so I know this post is maybe not incredibly informative.

Thanks.

Comment: I get a small transparent bar at the bottom of the window when I open "New Document" that disappears when I resize. I do not get your problem with base graphics in the quartz window. I am using R version 4.0.3 Patched (2020-12-26 r79698).

Comment: I'm also experiencing strange quartz device issues after updating to Big Sur. R 4.0.3. The quartz device window is sluggish to drag and resize. Sometimes the plots show up with bad resolution. Often ggplot plots don't update and I have to run a base R command (e.g. plot(1:10)) to "reset" the window so that subsequent ggplots will render.

Comment: @Ryan yep, I get some of those issues, too. It's sad, quartz used to be my favorite way to view and resize my graphics before saving. Sigh...